# Line chart legend color not getting update on button click (highcharts-angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using `highcharts-angular` in my angular applications. I have scenario where I need to change the color of line chart to some other color. (the legends and lines every thing should get updated with the new color that we provide). Please find below the code used:

HTML:

```
<highcharts-chart #lineChart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions" style="width: 100%;">
</highcharts-chart>
<button (click)="changeColor()">Change color</button>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more.src.js";
import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
HC_exporting(Highcharts);
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-high-chart-question",
  templateUrl: "./high-chart-question.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./high-chart-question.component.css"]
})
export class HighChartQuestionComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild("lineChart", { static: false }) lineChart: any;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions = {
   series: [
   {
    name: "Current - 2014",
    data: [
      {
        name: "1",
        y: 200030
      },
      {
        name: "2",
        y: 23300
      },
      {
        name: "3",
        y: 2300
      }
    ],
    color: "indigo"
   },
   {
    name: "Prior - 2013",
    data: [
      {
        name: "1",
        y: 90030
      },
      {
        name: "2",
        y: 23300
      },
      {
        name: "3",
        y: 672300
      }
    ],
    color: "green"
   }
 ],
 chart: {
  type: "line",
  renderTo: "chart"
 },
 title: {
  text: "Net activity along fiscal period accross years"
 },
 xAxis: {
  title: {
    text: "Fiscal Period"
  },
  type: "category"
 },
 yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: "Functional Amount"
  },
  gridLineWidth: 1
 },
 legend: {
  enabled: true,
  align: "right",
  verticalAlign: "middle",
  layout: "vertical"
 },
 credits: {
  enabled: false
 },
 plotOptions: {
  series: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    minPointLength: 3
  }
 },
 tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return (
      this.series.name + "<br/>" + this.x + " : " + "<b>" + this.y + "<b>"
    );
  }
 }
};

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {}

changeColor() {
  this.lineChart.chart.series.forEach((series, index) => {
  let colors: string[] = ["orange", "blue"];
  series.color = colors[index];
  series.data.forEach(data => {
    data.color = colors[index];
  });
 });
 this.lineChart.chart.update({});
}
}
```

Here the color of lines are changing, but the legends color are not getting updated on button click.

Demo Links:

https://highcharts-angular-functionality.stackblitz.io/exportcolor

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-functionality?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fhigh-chart-question%2Fhigh-chart-question.component.ts

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your **changeColor** function logic to:

```
  changeColor() {
    this.lineChart.chart.series.forEach((series, index) => {
      let colors: string[] = ["orange", "blue"];
      series.update({
        color: colors[index]
      })
    });
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-functionality-vjjwvh?file=src/app/stackoverflow/high-chart-question/high-chart-question.component.ts

**series.update** is a feature which redraws the whole series again - includes a legend.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the one I'm looking for.